# Creating lists based on operations on turtle-own variables

Tags: list, netlogo

I have 3 turtles and each has a size variable. I want to create a list of dimension 3 which will basically be % support size of each turtle with respect to the total size. List should look like

```
[turtle1-size / sum[size] of all turtles
turtle2-size / sum[size] of all turtles
turtle3-size / sum[size] of all turtle]
```

I know there are turtles-own and patches-own list but that will only contain the list of the turtle/patch names itself right?

Thanks, appreciate the help.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Here's one solution:

```
to-report proportions
  let total-size sum [size] of turtles
  report (list [size / total-size] of turtle 0
               [size / total-size] of turtle 1
               [size / total-size] of turtle 2)
end
```

let's try it:

```
observer> clear-all
observer> create-turtles 3 [ set size who ]
observer> show proportions
observer: [0 0.3333333333333333 0.6666666666666666]
```

Looks right to me.